# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How to solve this issue,**Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {cashback, image, logo, store_branches, store_id, store_name, store_summary, store_url}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**  I need **stores_list ** object data could you please help me.

My Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Grid} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import OwlCarousel from 'react-owl-carousel';
export default class ApiData extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }
 
    async componentDidMount() {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'React POST Request Example' })
    };

    const url = "https://localhost/api/v4/web/home";
    fetch(url,requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({ data: json.sections.collections});
        
         })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      });
  }
  
  render() {
     
    if (!this.state.data) {
      return null;
  }
     
   
    var i=0;
    var s;
    if (i<this.state.data.length){
     return s=this.state.data[i]["stores_list"];
    i++
    }
    console.log(s)
    return (
      <Grid className='slider-three'>
    </Grid>
         
      
    );
  }
};
```

my JSON:

```
collections": [
            {
                "home_offer_id": 71,
                "stores_list": [
                    {
                        "cashback": "200",
                        "image": "https://dl8mjowvdz1rh.cloudfront.net/stores/Nara_Pan_Asis_Detail_1620125271937.jpeg",
                        "logo": "https://dl8mjowvdz1rh.cloudfront.net/stores/Nara_Pan_Asia_Logo_1620125267963.jpeg",
                        "store_branches": [
                            {
                                "store_city": "Dubai",
                                "store_location": "JLT"
                            }
                        ],
                        "store_id": 120,
                        "store_name": "NARA Pan Asian",
                        "store_summary": "JLT, Brunch, Asian, Japanese, Thai, Chinese",
                        "store_url": "/store/nara-pan-asian/120"
                    }
                ]
            }
]
}
```

Comment: Could you please solve this issue?

Comment: Probably this line causes the error `return s=this.state.data[i]["stores_list"];`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, can you please alternate options could you please provide me. thanks

Comment: I just provided you alternate options. Please mark my answer as correct if it was helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You get that error when you try to return an {Object} instead of a [Array].

Reading your code it seems its likely coming from `return s=this.state.data[i]["stores_list"];`. Try using .map method to return an array of the results.

What you want to try to return should look like `[{<Object>},{<Object>},{<Object>}]`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Grid} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import OwlCarousel from 'react-owl-carousel';
export default class ApiData extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }
    async componentDidMount() {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'React POST Request Example' })
    };

    const url = "https://localhost/api/v4/web/home";
    fetch(url,requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({ data: json.sections.collections});
        
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      });
  }
  
  render() {
    if (!this.state.data){
      return null;
    }
    const storesList = []
    for (let index = 0; index < this.state.data.length; index++) {
      const element = this.state.data[index];
      storesList.push(element);
    }
    return (
      <Grid className='slider-three'></Grid>
    )
  }
}
```

Try using the Array Instance Method `.map()` which expects a callback function. That callback function `(store)=>store['stores_list']` is applied to each item and returns a brand new array for you in the `storesList` constant which is now an Array that looks like `[{this.data[0]['stores_list']}, {this.data[1]['stores_list']}, {this.data[2]['stores_list']}, ..., {this.data[i]['stores_list']}]` for `i` stores such that `i` === `this.data.length`.

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Yes, I need this structure [{<Object>},{<Object>},{<Object>}]

Comment: Great to hear! Please mark my answer as correct then! Glad to help! (Incase you're not sure how to do that, go to my answer and click the green checkmark and upvote it)

Comment: Hello Sir can you please use this inside loop .[{this.data[0]['stores_list']}, {this.data[1]['stores_list']}, {this.data[2]['stores_list']}, ..., {this.data[i]['stores_list']}] for i stores such that i === this.data.length.

Comment: This feels like I a homework assignment. Please mark it correct if it worked, and if this is your homework, try it on your own or ask your friends or colleagues, using stack overflow in the long run is a surefire way to waste your time doing CS.

`const storesList = []
    for (let index = 0; index < this.state.data.length; index++) {
      const element = this.state.data[index];
      storesList.push(element);
    }`